# ¿Cómo pongo el botón al final de la pagina?

Tags: html, css

Tengo una pagina y quiero poner le botón abajo del todo pero no lo consigo. (Salvo que me hinche a poner  entonces si jaja. os dejo código y una foto de como se ve

```
<?php session_start(); ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylo.css">
        <title>tarea online hlc 03</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: cornsilk">
        <?php include'BarraDCabecera.php'; ?>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="card" style="margin-right: 15px; float:right; background-color: activecaption; width: 35rem;">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Xperia 5</h4>                       
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="imagenes/xperia.jpg">
                        <div class="card-body">                                
                            <p class="card-text">Cámara con tres objetivos</br>
                                Autoenfoque de ojos </br> 
                                Pantalla OLED FHD+ HDR de 21:9 </br>
                                Plataforma móvil Qualcomm® Snapdragon™ 855  </br>
                                DIMENSIONES 158 × 68 × 8,2 mm  </br>
                                PESO 164 g  </br>
                                RESISTENTE AL AGUA (IP65/68)  </br>
                                Doble SIM  </br>
                                Bateria 3140 mAh</p>
                            <p> Precio 700€ </p></p>
                            <button type="button">Comprar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>            
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="card" style="margin-left: 15px; float: left;background-color: activecaption; width: 35rem;">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Galaxy Z Flip</h4>
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="imagenes/galaxy.jpg">
                        <div class="card-body">                           
                            <p class="card-text">PANTALLA: </br>
                                Interior: Dynamic AMOLED plegable 6,7"  </br>
                                Exterior: Super AMOLED 1,06"  </br>
                                PROCESADOR: Snapdragon 855+  </br>
                                RAM 8 GB </br>
                                ALMACENAMIENTO 256 GB UFS 3.0  </br>
                                SOFTWARE Android 10 + One UI 2.0 </br>
                                CÁMARA TRASERA: </br>
                                Gran angular 12 MP, f/1.8, 1.4µm, Dual Pixel PDAF, OIS  </br>
                                Ultra gran angular 12 MP, f/2.2  </br>
                                CÁMARA FRONTAL: </br>
                                10 MP, f/2.4, PDAF  </br>
                                BATERÍA: 3.300 mAh  </br>
                                CONECTIVIDAD WiFi ac, BT 5.0, NFC, USB-C  </br>
                                OTROS:  </br>
                                Altavoces estéreo AKG, sensor de huellas lateral</br>
                                DIMENSIONES Y PESO:  </br>
                                Desplegado: 167,9 x 73,6 x 7,2 mm  </br>
                                Plegado: 87,4 x 73,6 x 17,3 mm  </br>
                                183 g  </p>
                            <p> PRECIO 1.500 euros</p>                            
                            </br>
                            <button type="button">Comprar</button>                      
                        </div>
                    </div>               
                </div>
            </div>       
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="card" style="margin-top: 25px; margin-left: 15px; float: left;background-color: activecaption; width: 35rem;">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Xiaomi mi9</h4>
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="imagenes/XiaomiMi9664GBOceanBlueLibre-i1.jpg">
                        <div class="card-body">                           
                            <p class="card-text">
                                PANTALLA: Super AMOLED 6,39",1.080x2.280 px, 19:9 </br>
                                PROCESADOR: Snapdragon 855</br>
                                RAM 8 GB </br>
                                ALMACENAMIENTO 64 / 128 / 256 GB</br>
                                SOFTWARE Android 9 Pie + MIUI 10 </br>
                                CÁMARA TRASERA: 48MP f/1.8 + 16MP f/2.2(gran angular) + 12MP</br>
                                CÁMARA FRONTAL: 20 megapíxeles</br>
                                BATERÍA: 3.300 mAh  </br>
                                CONECTIVIDAD WiFi 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac, dual band, Bluetooth 5.0</br>
                                DIMENSIONES Y PESO: 155 x 75 x 7,6 mm, 173 gramos </br>
                                OTROS:  </br>
                                SENSORES Acelerómetro, giroscopio, barómetro, proximidad </br>
                                Lector de huellas en pantalla</p>
                            USB tipo C, GPS dual, NFC</p>
                            <p> PRECIO:</br>
                                6 GB + 128 GB: 499 euros</br>
                                4 GB + 64 GB 449 euros</p>
                            </br></br>
                            <button type="button">Comprar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="card" style="margin-top: 25px; margin-right: 15px; float: right;background-color: activecaption; width: 35rem;">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Moto G8 plus</h4>
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="imagenes/Motorola-Moto-G8-specs.jpg">
                        <div class="card-body">                           
                            <p class="card-text">
                                PANTALLA: IPS LCD de 6,3 pulgadas FullHD+ Formato 19:9</br>
                                PROCESADOR: Snapdragon 665 a 2GHz GPU Adreno 610</br>
                                RAM 4 GB </br>
                                ALMACENAMIENTO 64 / 128 GB</br>
                                SOFTWARE Android 9 Pie </br>
                                CÁMARA TRASERA: 448mpx f/1.7 + 16mpx f/2.2(ultra angular) + 5mpx f/2.2</br>
                                CÁMARA FRONTAL: 25 megapíxeles</br>
                                BATERÍA: 4.000 mAh  </br>
                                CONECTIVIDAD WiFi 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac, dual band, Bluetooth 5.0</br>
                                DIMENSIONES Y PESO: 9.1 milímetros de grosor 188 gramos </br>
                                OTROS:  </br>
                                SENSORES Acelerómetro, giroscopio, barómetro, proximidad </br>
                                Lector de huellas trasero</p>
                            USB tipo C, GPS dual, NFC</p>
                            <p> PRECIO:</br>
                                4 GB + 128 GB: 300 euros</br>
                                4 GB + 64 GB 220 euros</p>
                            <button type="button">Comprar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>           
        </div>    
    </body>
    <footer>
        <a href="pagina2.php"><button name="siguiente">Siguiente</button>
    </footer>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado a poner otro  `<div class="row">` y meterlo dentro he probado a meterlo debajo del body sin el footer no se me ocurren mas cosas

Comment: Sin tener tu **CSS** cualquier solución que se te de es papel mojado, ya que lo que tú tengas puede entrar en conflicto con la solución.

Comment: He añadido la etiqueta ya que no parece ser un requerimiento no usar **CSS** puesto que se usa `inline` en los elementos. Por otra parte no es una buena solución poner un elemento de paginado en el footer (Supongo que lo haces para intentar que se quede abajo del todo).

Comment: puedes usar un `div` y adentro poner el boton pero ese `div` debes ponerlo por debajo de todo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el código que planteas lo que necesitarías es darle una posición fija en el 'bottom' de tu código a ese botón, por lo que la manera más sencilla de hacerlo es mediante un 'position'. En este caso yo he otorgado a tu 'container' un 'position relative' y al 'footer' un 'position: absolute; bottom: 15px' enviando al fondo del todo el botón. Además he modificado tu código levemente, ya que había algunos pequeños errores y de este modo sirve también para que se vea y entienda el cambio en el editor de SO. He quitado tus estilos en línea y puesto dentro de la clase de 'css' que corresponde. Comparto aquí debajo el código:

```css
.container {position:relative;}

footer {position:absolute; bottom:15px; right:15px;}

.card {display: inline-block; background-color: activecaption; width: 35rem; margin:15px}
```

```html
<?php session_start(); ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylo.css">
        <title>tarea online hlc 03</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: cornsilk">
        <?php include'BarraDCabecera.php'; ?>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="card">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Galaxy Z Flip</h4>
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="imagenes/galaxy.jpg">
                        <div class="card-body">                           
                            <p class="card-text">PANTALLA: <br>
                                Interior: Dynamic AMOLED plegable 6,7"  <br>
                                Exterior: Super AMOLED 1,06"  <br>
                                PROCESADOR: Snapdragon 855+  <br>
                                RAM 8 GB <br>
                                ALMACENAMIENTO 256 GB UFS 3.0  <br>
                                SOFTWARE Android 10 + One UI 2.0 <br>
                                CÁMARA TRASERA: <br>
                                Gran angular 12 MP, f/1.8, 1.4µm, Dual Pixel PDAF, OIS  <br>
                                Ultra gran angular 12 MP, f/2.2  <br>
                                CÁMARA FRONTAL: <br>
                                10 MP, f/2.4, PDAF  <br>
                                BATERÍA: 3.300 mAh  <br>
                                CONECTIVIDAD WiFi ac, BT 5.0, NFC, USB-C  <br>
                                OTROS:  <br>
                                Altavoces estéreo AKG, sensor de huellas lateral<br>
                                DIMENSIONES Y PESO:  <br>
                                Desplegado: 167,9 x 73,6 x 7,2 mm  <br>
                                Plegado: 87,4 x 73,6 x 17,3 mm  <br>
                                183 g  </p>
                            <p> PRECIO 1.500 euros</p>                            
                            <br>
                            <button type="button">Comprar</button>                      
                        </div>
                    </div>               
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="card">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Xperia 5</h4>                       
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="imagenes/xperia.jpg">
                        <div class="card-body">                                
                            <p class="card-text">Cámara con tres objetivos<br>
                                Autoenfoque de ojos <br> 
                                Pantalla OLED FHD+ HDR de 21:9 <br>
                                Plataforma móvil Qualcomm® Snapdragon™ 855  <br>
                                DIMENSIONES 158 × 68 × 8,2 mm  <br>
                                PESO 164 g  <br>
                                RESISTENTE AL AGUA (IP65/68)  <br>
                                Doble SIM  <br>
                                Bateria 3140 mAh</p>
                            <p> Precio 700€ </p>
                            <button type="button">Comprar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>            
                      
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="card">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Xiaomi mi9</h4>
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="imagenes/XiaomiMi9664GBOceanBlueLibre-i1.jpg">
                        <div class="card-body">                           
                            <p class="card-text">
                                PANTALLA: Super AMOLED 6,39",1.080x2.280 px, 19:9 <br>
                                PROCESADOR: Snapdragon 855<br>
                                RAM 8 GB <br>
                                ALMACENAMIENTO 64 / 128 / 256 GB<br>
                                SOFTWARE Android 9 Pie + MIUI 10 <br>
                                CÁMARA TRASERA: 48MP f/1.8 + 16MP f/2.2(gran angular) + 12MP<br>
                                CÁMARA FRONTAL: 20 megapíxeles<br>
                                BATERÍA: 3.300 mAh  <br>
                                CONECTIVIDAD WiFi 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac, dual band, Bluetooth 5.0<br>
                                DIMENSIONES Y PESO: 155 x 75 x 7,6 mm, 173 gramos <br>
                                OTROS:  <br>
                                SENSORES Acelerómetro, giroscopio, barómetro, proximidad <br>
                                Lector de huellas en pantalla<br>
                                USB tipo C, GPS dual, NFC</p>
                            <p> PRECIO:<br>
                                6 GB + 128 GB: 499 euros<br>
                                4 GB + 64 GB 449 euros<p>
                            <br><br>
                            <button type="button">Comprar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="card">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Moto G8 plus</h4>
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="imagenes/Motorola-Moto-G8-specs.jpg">
                        <div class="card-body">                           
                            <p class="card-text">
                                PANTALLA: IPS LCD de 6,3 pulgadas FullHD+ Formato 19:9<br>
                                PROCESADOR: Snapdragon 665 a 2GHz GPU Adreno 610<br>
                                RAM 4 GB <br>
                                ALMACENAMIENTO 64 / 128 GB<br>
                                SOFTWARE Android 9 Pie <br>
                                CÁMARA TRASERA: 448mpx f/1.7 + 16mpx f/2.2(ultra angular) + 5mpx f/2.2<br>
                                CÁMARA FRONTAL: 25 megapíxeles<br>
                                BATERÍA: 4.000 mAh  <br>
                                CONECTIVIDAD WiFi 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac, dual band, Bluetooth 5.0<br>
                                DIMENSIONES Y PESO: 9.1 milímetros de grosor 188 gramos <br>
                                OTROS:  <br>
                                SENSORES Acelerómetro, giroscopio, barómetro, proximidad <br>
                                Lector de huellas trasero<br>
                            USB tipo C, GPS dual, NFC</p>
                            <p> PRECIO:<br>
                                4 GB + 128 GB: 300 euros<br>
                                4 GB + 64 GB 220 euros</p>
                            <button type="button">Comprar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>   
            <footer>
                <a href="pagina2.php"><button name="siguiente">Siguiente</button></a>
            </footer>
        </div>   

    </body>
</html>
```

Espero haberte podido ayudar. Comparto a continuación un enlace con la documentación sobre el uso del 'position' en css por si te resultase de ayuda bien en este caso o en otros: [Position - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: Acabo de probar eso me pone el boton a la derecha arriba no abajo

Comment: Si coges el código tal y como te lo he puesto funciona. De todas formas en CSS que he puesto de ve como organizar los position.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un footer, intenta de la siguiente forma

```
<div class="card-body">                           
    <p class="card-text">Texto</p>
     AQUI TIENES UN ERROR POR QUE CIERRAS UN P QUE NO ABRISTE</p>
    <p>Texto</p>
</div>
<div class="card-footer text-muted">
    <button type="button">Comprar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: no sirve eso no me baja el boton abajo del todo

Comment: ¿Qué tan abajo lo necesitas? ¿Quieres que adivinemos?

Comment: abajo del todo no te da una idea? abajo del todo creo que esta claro que es debajo de todo lo que haya